# How to calculate $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1-k\sin{kx}}{2^k} dx $?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have to find $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1-k\sin{kx}}{2^k} dx$, but can't figure out how to do it.

If $\frac{1-k\sin{kx}}{2^k}$ converges it would be easy to calculate $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1-k\sin{kx}}{2^k} dx$, but I don't know how to prove the convergence and how to find the sum. The answer of the integral should be $\frac{1}{2^k}\left(\frac{\pi }{2}+\cos \left(\frac{\pi k}{2}\right)-1\right)$ and I think the convergence can be proved with Weierstrass. If I'm correct the solution can be found with $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}\left(\frac{\pi }{2}+\cos \left(\frac{\pi k}{2}\right)-1\right)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $k\in\Bbb Z_+$ and each $x\in\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$,$$\left|\frac{1-k\sin(kx)}{2^k}\right|\leqslant\frac{1+k}{2^k}.$$Since the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1+k}{2^k}$ (by, say, the ratio test), your series converges uniformly on $\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$, by the Weierstrass $M$-test. So\begin{align}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1-k\sin(kx)}{2^k}\,\mathrm dx&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1-k\sin(kx)}{2^k}\,\mathrm dx\\&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{-1+\pi/2+\cos\left(k\pi/2\right)}{2^k}\\&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{-1+\pi/2}{2^k}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2^{2k}}\\&=-2+\pi+\frac1{1+1/4}\\&=\pi-\frac65.\end{align}